# Expected custom exception in Junit 5 Assertions.assertThrows but nothing was thrown

Tags: mockito, junit5, assertion

Any chance that some one can enlighten me with where is the mistake?

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ServiceTest {
    @Mock
    EntryService service;

    @InjectMocks
    EntryController controller;

    @Test
    void testException() {
       Mockito.when(service.addNewEntry(Mockito.any(EntryDTO.class))).thenThrow(new EntryNotFound("Entry not found"));
       Assertions.assertThrows(EntryNotFound.class, () -> {
           controller.saveNewEntry(new EntryDTO());
    });
    }
```

I'm getting:
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected com.example.exception.EntryNotFound to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.

Funnily enough, when I'm running the following test, everything seems to work just fine:

```
    void testSuccess() {
    Mockito.when(service.addNewEntry(Mockito.any(EntryDTO.class))).thenReturn(entry);
    ResponseEntity<Entry> entry = controller.saveNewEntry(new EntryDTO());
    Assertions.assertNotNull(entry);
    Assertions.assertEquals(1l, entry.getBody().getId());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just before sending the question I stumbled upon the answer. Since it has got my puzzled for a while I decide to share it in case it may be of any help to some one else.

Basically **assertThrows()** checks for exceptions that are **not being already catched**.

If I avoid catching the exception on:

```
controller.saveNewEntry(new EntryDTO()
```

then the test would have passed.

Comment: ```controller.saveNewEntry(new EntryDTO())```. This method is handling the exception?